# Pasar el valor de una variable como dato Php

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, wordpress

He creado una función que me recoge los datos de una base de datos y los muestra en pantalla por medio de `<input>` para que el usuario pueda ver sus datos y si los desea modificar cuando le de a un botón se ejecute otra función distinta y se haga un update en la base de datos.

Vale todo bien hasta el momento de hacer el update, quiero que al hacer el update se tenga en cuenta que el id del usuario obtenido es el que se va a modificar en la base de datos.

El problema es que uso WordPress y uso la clase `$wpdb` la cual para usar la sentencia `where` me pide que le pase el valor en "bruto" es decir le pase el valor en si no una variable.

No se como puedo mostrar un valor para que el programa trabaje con el.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $idCliente = (int) $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT clientesID FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta=%s AND Clavetarjeta=%s",$mParams));

$nombretabla = "nikkiclub";
$dataupdate = array('nombretutor1' => $nombretutor1, 'apellidostutor1' => $apellidostutor1, 'dnitutor1' => $dnitutor1, 'nombretutor2' => $nombretutor2, 'apellidostutor2' => $apellidostutor2, 'dnitutor2' => $dnitutor2);
$where = array('clientesID' => $idCliente);
$format = array('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');
$where_format = array('%d');

if (isset($_POST['modificar'])) {

    global $wpdb;
    $update=$wpdb->update($nombretabla,$dataupdate,$where,$format,$where_format);

}
```

El problema esta en el `$where` que recibe el valor `$idcliente` el cual obtengo por medio de sql desde la base de datos.

Al cambiar el `$idCliente` por un valor introducido por mi si me hace el update, pero claro necesito que el valor cambie dependiendo del cliente que use la aplicacion.

Comment: Por favor no hagas varias veces la misma pregunta --> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/241072/no-se-me-actualiza-la-base-de-datos

Comment: Si te funciona cambiando por un numero es que estas recuperando mal el valor.

Comment: Solucionado lo de dos veces la misma pregunta (que si lo lees bien no es lo mismo pero bueno si es parecido), y como recuperaría el valor? por que comprobando con `var_dump` me dice que `$idCliente` es un dato tipo `int` con el valor que le corresponde pero claro al usarlo en una variable no me funciona

Comment: Lo que te  indica la ayuda del [update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/) es : **"Both $data columns and $data values should be "raw" (neither should be SQL escaped)."** Es decir, su valor no debe estar [*escapado*](http://php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.escape.php) lo cual no tiene nada que ver con lo que dices de *"en "bruto" es decir le pase el valor en si no una variable"* lo cual no tiene ningún sentido, los valores se pasan en variables, por lo tanto no le des más vueltas a ese tema y focaliza la atención en lo demás, hay algo que pasas por alto.

Comment: Quizá te pueda ayudar esto  `$wpdb->last_query` (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110269) Saca las dos consultas, la que funciona y la que no y a ver que diferencias hay.

Comment: Lo hare ya mismo a ver que me da gracias

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver al darle a modificar los datos, el valor del id pasa a ser `null` y el update no se llega a hacer por eso

Answer (score 0):

Creo que comprendo tu problema. Revisando la documentación que nos facilita **Wordpress** en referencia a la clase `$wpdb`, leyendo lo que necesita que le pases en el `where` es un array asociativo cuya clave y valor estén en **raw**.

Para tratar de solucionar ese inconveniente se me ocurre lo siguiente. Partiendo de un `array()` vacío y usando una pequeña función, podríamos alcanzar lo que creo que necesitas. No tengo escenario de pruebas para comprobarlo así que coméntame que tal te fue para poder buscar otra solución sobre la marcha.

```
$id_cliente = 5;
$where = array();

$where = array_push_assoc($where, 'id_cliente', $id_cliente);

var_dump($where);

function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
}
```

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es pasarle este array a la función update como parámetro del `where`. Quedando algo así:

```
$update=$wpdb->update($nombretabla,$dataupdate,$where,$format,$where_format);
```

Comment: Mmmm no veo como esto podría solucionar el error pero lo probare, el problema que tengo es que almaceno en `$idCliente` el resultado de una consulta como un int `    $idCliente = (int) $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT clientesID FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta=%s AND Clavetarjeta=%s",$mParams));` y esta variable la quiero pasar por el `where` pero no me ejecuta el update a no se que en la variable en vez de hacerlo así lo pase como dato numérico (`$idCliente=2` por ejemplo), lo probare aun así y gracias por intentar ayudar

Comment: ¿Y estás seguro de que **$idCliente = (int) $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT clientesID FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta=%s AND Clavetarjeta=%s",$mParams));`** devuelve la id que esperas? Porque me basé en que $idCliente tenía lo que necesitabas a la hora de buscar una posible causa de lo que te estaba pasando. Lo que yo haría sería un **echo** a la variable justo después de darle valor para comprobar que te está devolviendo el número de id o por el contrario te está devolviendo otra cosa.

Comment: si me devuelve el valor que tiene que devolver pero el `$update` no hace el trabajo y es por que no recoge la variable bien a no se que la pase como numero y eso que al hacer el select lo paso como `(int)` pero nada no hay forma.

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el resultado que te da al hacer  **var_dump($idCliente)**? Quiero ver lo que te devuelve la query exactamente.

Comment: int(1) o int(2) vamos el valor del id del usuario que toque

Comment: Vamos a ver lo que se le envía al servidor SQL. Después de tu update pon: **exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );** A ver si viendo la query escrita podemos ver lo que puede estar pasando.

Comment: me devuelve el sql pero con el dato del where como null `UPDATE `nikkiclub` SET `nombretutor1` = 'pepe', `apellidostutor1` = 'valido', `dnitutor1` = '26262626a', `nombretutor2` = 'juana', `apellidostutor2` = 'valido', `dnitutor2` = '878787878a' WHERE `clientesID` IS NULL`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90371/discussion-between-phpmyguel-and-acoidan-negrin-socorro).